# Simple Fibonacci sequence not ouputting correct answer in Python

Tags: python, while-loop, fibonacci

Here's a very simple script, yet when you call the function with any number, it turns out wrong.

```
def fib(n):
     a=0
     b=1
     while a < n:
         a, b = b, a+b
     print(a)
```

fib(10) = 13. Which is wrong.

Comment: Your function return the first value in the Fibonacci sequence greater than or equal to n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def fib(n):
     a=0
     b=1
     i=1
     while i < n:
        a, b = b, a+b
        i+=1
     print(b)
```

try this ^^

you can not use a because a is not rising linear, it is rising depending on your current fibonacci calculation status... so you need an extra counter for taking in what step you are

Comment: Thank you. I still don't quite understand why my code doesn't work though.

Comment: when you do fibonacci sequences and you give in let's say 10, you have to iterate 10 times over your calculation to get the correct value... but you used a as your stepper, but actually a is rising like 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13 and that because it is used in your calculation... a rises based on the fibonacci sequence, not based on the steps you need to take, that is the problem :) you just needed to take an extra variable to count your steps (because you need 10 of them)

Comment: Please consider using a for loop over `range(n)` instead of incrementing `i` manually.

Comment: yeah you are right I am not a pyhton expert I have to admit